# How to have content script appear in firefox debugger

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have a firefox addon I made that has this line of code

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')
```

`document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')` only seems to refer to the current tab when I run in it web console but when it's packaged in an addon. imgs.length = 0 even though I know the page in the current tab has img tags because it worked fine in the web console. What do I need to add tell javascript to refer to the html on the current page?

Also that line is within a function that is called with this.

```
var current = browser.tabs.getCurrent();
current.then(listenForClick, report);
```

Why doesn't `then.current` imply for the listenForClick function to be executed for the webpage on the current tab?

When I loaded the addon as a temporary I figured it was because temporaries are restricted to viewing the webpage that loaded them but even after getting the addon signed so I can officially load it in firefox like a real addon the issue mentioned above persisted.

**Update**

After reading the comment by Jaromanda X I tried to do the content script method again and this time it worked. This made my day as the whole process of developing my first ever browser extension was a very frustrating and painful process. I don't like that in JS arguments can be implicitly passed to functions. IMO that makes JS very hard to read for someone reading someone elses code. Also due to the painful process of doing this I still have one last question. How come a content script doesn't appear in the firefox debugger when you temporarily load an addon. (even if listed in the manifest file which oddly enough breaks my addon since I already have a background script mentioned in mine but even for an sample addon that only had a content script and therefore mentioned it in its manifest file the content script STILL didn't appear in the debugger)  If I was able to debug my content script from the start when I tried to use a content script earlier in the development process I probably wouldn't have made this question.

P.S. I wasn't able to find an answer to that when googling.

Comment: I think you'll need a `content script`

Comment: I tried doing that too but the same issue occurred. Plus not being able to view the content script file in the debugger made it very frustrating. At first I thought it was because using localStorage to store arrays wasn't working but after googling that and seeing that I had to do it via JSON I now see the issue was the same as the one I mention above.